# Reference request: pro-algebraic completion

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, homological-algebra

The pro-algebraic completion $G^{\mathrm{alg}}$ of a discrete group $G$ is the initial pro-algebraic group with a morphism $G\to G^{\mathrm{alg}}$. This construction is functorial.

Does anyone have any good references for the basic properties of the pro-algebraic completion functor?

Comment: Maybe Milne’s book on affine group schemes has some material; at least over a field this should be the affine group scheme you get by Tannaka reconstruction applied to the category of $G$-representations, and Milne has some stuff on that.